# How to create a custom health check for Prisma with @nestjs/terminus?

Tags: nestjs, prisma, health-check

Since [@nestjs/terminus](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus) doesn't provide a health check for Prisma, I'm trying to create it based on their [Mongoose health check](https://github.com/nestjs/terminus/blob/master/lib/health-indicator/database/mongoose.health.ts).

When I try:

```
import * as Prisma from 'prisma';
...
...
  private getContextConnection(): any | null {
    const {
      getConnectionToken,
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
    } = require('prisma') as typeof Prisma;

    try {
      return this.moduleRef.get(getConnectionToken('DatabaseConnection') as string, {
        strict: false,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
...
...
    const connection = options.connection || this.getContextConnection();

    if (!connection) {
      throw new ConnectionNotFoundError(
        this.getStatus(key, isHealthy, {
          message: 'Connection provider not found in application context',
        }),
      );
    }
```

I always seem to get: "message": "Connection provider not found in application context".
There is a problem with the connection or I don't really understand how the health check actually works

Comment: Since there's no NestJS Prisma package and therefore nobody registers the `DatabaseConnection` token, it probably makes more sense to do `PrismaClient.$connect()` in the health check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive copy of the mongoose implementation isn't going to work because there are differences between the `NestJSMongoose` type/module and `Prisma`. In particular, `getConnectionToken` does not exist inside the `Prisma` package.

I can't comment on what the best way would be to extend terminus to support prisma. You might have to dig a bit into the `terminus` interface for that. However, a simple way to get a health check/ping  in Prisma is to use the following query:

```js
    prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT 1`
```

Answer (score 10):

This question helped me build a Prisma health check for NestJS.

Here's what I made:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { HealthCheckError, HealthIndicator, HealthIndicatorResult } from "@nestjs/terminus";
import { PrismaService } from "./prisma.service";

@Injectable()
export class PrismaHealthIndicator extends HealthIndicator {
  constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {
    super();
  }

  async isHealthy(key: string): Promise<HealthIndicatorResult> {
    try {
      await this.prismaService.$queryRaw`SELECT 1`;
      return this.getStatus(key, true);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new HealthCheckError("Prisma check failed", e);
    }
  }
}
```

This injects a `PrismaService` exactly as it is shown in the NestJS docs. https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma#use-prisma-client-in-your-nestjs-services

You could alternatively replace `prismaService` with `new PrismaClient()`.

Comment: Could you please add an example of how you'd use `PrismaHealthIndicator` in a health check controller

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71445270/520105) is very good, but if you want the error state to be properly formatted you should throw the error like this:

```js
// keep in mind that it is not recommended to send server errors directly to the client,
// you may not want to expose your DB location or other sensitive data
Logger.error(error, `${PrismaHealthIndicator.name}::isHealthy`)

throw new HealthCheckError(
  'cannot perform DB checks',
  this.getStatus(key, false, {
    message: 'cannot perform DB checks'
  })
)
```

docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus#custom-health-indicator